# Problems while converting a tuple-dict to a valid dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, tuples, dictionary-comprehension

Given the code snippet below

```
tupled-dict:{
 ('apples', 'no'): 1,
 ('apples', 'yes'): 1,
 ('grapes', 'no'): 5,
 ('grapes', 'yes'): 6,
 ('cherry', 'no'): 2,
 ('cherry', 'yes'): 2,
 ('orange', 'yes'): 3,
 ("mango's of india", 'no'): 1,
 ("mango's of india", 'yes'): 1,
 ('chocolate', 'no'): 2,
 ('chocolate', 'yes'): 2,
 ('tomatoes', 'no'): 2,
 ('tomatoes', 'yes'): 3,
 ('pineapple', 'no'): 4,
 ('pineapple', 'yes'): 2,
 ('peas', 'no'): 3}
```

How can I create a shorter version like this:

```
{'apples': {'availability': {'yes': 1, 'no': 1}},
 'grapes': {'availability': {'yes': 6, 'no': 5}},
 'cherry': {'availability': {'yes': 2, 'no': 2}},
 'orange': {'availability': {'yes': 3, 'no': 0}},
 "mango's of india": {'availability': {'yes': 1, 'no': 1}},
 'chocolate': {'availability': {'yes': 2, 'no': 2}},
 'tomatoes': {'availability': {'yes': 2, 'no': 3}},
 'pineapple': {'availability': {'yes': 4, 'no': 2}},
 'peas': {'availability': {'yes': 3, 'no': 0}}}
```

I tried to iterate throught the tuples, and extract the each fruit and availability to create and nest the dictionary like this:

```
l=[]
helper_dict = {}

for e in a_dict.keys():
    l.append(e)
    fruits = list(set([i[0] for i in l]))

for e in fruits:
    try:
        helper_dict[e]['Yes']= a_dict[str(e),'Yes']
    except KeyError:
        helper_dict[e]['Yes']= 0
```

However, I am finding it complicated to create this structure when there is missing one availability. For example, `('peas', 'no'): 3` only has 3:no, as there is no `('peas', 'yes')`, I would assume and update the dictionary as `('peas', 'no'): 0`. Same for `orange`, because there is only `3:yes`, and `0:no`. Any idea of how to do this less complicated?

Comment: Why do you need the dict with the single property `availability`? Are you planning on adding more properties later?

Comment: @Aplet123 yes, possibly, I want to leave it as "flexible" as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put the new `availability` dict in when it is missing:

```py
a_dict = {('apples', 'no'): 1,
 ('apples', 'yes'): 1,
 ('grapes', 'no'): 5,
 ('grapes', 'yes'): 6,
 ('cherry', 'no'): 2,
 ('cherry', 'yes'): 2,
 ('orange', 'yes'): 3,
 ("mango's of india", 'no'): 1,
 ("mango's of india", 'yes'): 1,
 ('chocolate', 'no'): 2,
 ('chocolate', 'yes'): 2,
 ('tomatoes', 'no'): 2,
 ('tomatoes', 'yes'): 3,
 ('pineapple', 'no'): 4,
 ('pineapple', 'yes'): 2,
 ('peas', 'no'): 3}

out_dict = {}
for k,v in a_dict.items():
    fruit,yn = k
    if fruit not in out_dict:
        out_dict[fruit] = {'availability': {}}
    out_dict[fruit]['availability'][yn] = v


print(out_dict)
```

Output as requested

The line `fruit,yn = k` is extracting individual items from the keys in `a_dict`.  For example, the first key in the code above is: `('apples', 'no')` which is a tuple and this is `k` in the `for` loop. This gets split into `fruit,yn` so that `fruit = 'apples'` and `yn = 'no'`.

Now that we have the key of `fruit = 'apples'` we can update the new dict `out_dict`. This dict is like nested 3 levels deep. First you have the key `fruit`, then below that you have invented the key `'availability'`, and below that you have the keys: `'yes' and 'no'`.

The penultimate line of the loop creates the lower level dicts if not already present, but the last line does an update of the inner most dict where `[fruit]` picks from the top level, `['availability']` picks the constant intermediate level and `[yn]` picks from either the `'yes'` or `'no'` keys.

Comment: did not knoe that you could do `yn=k`. Could you explain this step, and `[yn]=v`? Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can add defaults when first creating a new dict:

```py
result_dict = {}

for ((fruit, cond), val) in a_dict.items():
    if fruit not in result_dict:
        # first insertion, so add defaults
        to_insert = {}
        for key in ["no", "yes"]:
            to_insert[key] = 0
        to_insert[cond] = val
        result_dict[fruit] = {"availability": to_insert}
    else:
        result_dict[fruit]["availability"][cond] = val

print(result_dict)
```